# Content statistics: The "Most Recent" view is not populated

Tags: 7, views

I have views in my Drupal 7 site that show the last 4 viewed objects. rather, it's supposed to do so. Instead it shows 4 objects views almost 2 years ago, coinciding when we had an ISP migration.

I have built a very basic view to show me just the titles and the most-recent-view of the objecs, and I can see that the Content Statistics: Most Recent View field is null for nearly everything the past two years. (This is impacting other views as well, such as my "Ten Most Viewed" which has also remained stagnant.)

Has anyone encountered this in their Drupal 7 sites and found how to turn back on this information gathering?

Comment: Did you restore the database from 2 years ago? Is the module recording views enabled?

Comment: Yes to both. All data from the original ISP was ported over to the new ISP and restored there, and the Statistics module is enabled. We've added a few thousand nodes since that time, none of which are getting the Most Recent View value populated.